# How to find the quantile value of each number in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have the following code which produces df with random values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
random_data = np.random.randint(10, 25, size=20)
df = pd.DataFrame(random_data, columns=['RANDOM VALUES'])
df.index.name = 'foo'
print(df)
```

This will produce:

```
     RANDOM VALUES
foo               
0               15
1               20
2               17
3               21
4               23
5               20
6               23
7               22
8               22
9               21
10              23
11              17
12              12
13              17
14              17
15              24
16              13
17              20
18              14
19              22
```

To find the quantile value for say `quantile(0.5)`

```
df['RANDOM VALUES'].quantile(0.5)
```

How can i do it the other way round? Such as create a column with quantile value of each number?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? The "quantile value of each number" does not make sense. For instance, `df['RANDOM VALUES'].quantile(0.5)` is the median value of the numbers in the "RANDOM VALUES" column. It does not make any sense to compute this value for each number separately.

Comment: Sort your values, ascending, then add a column to `df` with `np.linspace(0,1, len(df)+1)[1:]`

Comment: @Sheldon I was looking to find where each value stands compared to all the values in the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `percentileofscore` function from the `scipy.stats` module. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html) for proper use of the `kind` argument:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

df["RANDOM VALUES"].apply(lambda x: stats.percentileofscore(df["RANDOM VALUES"],
                                                             x, kind = 'weak'))
```